# Probability of generating a primitive group of given type with 2 elements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm interested in the following question:

> Given $g,h \in S_n$, what is the probability that $ \langle g,h \rangle$ is a primitive group of given O'Nan-Scott-type?

Can someone point me towards interesting literature concerning this problem? I know there is a lot of work on the expected number of elements to generate a group (i.e. formulas using the Moebius function on the subgroup lattice), but I can't seem to find anything concerning the above question.

Comment: Since the probability of generating $A_n$ or $S_n$ approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$, surely the answer to your question must be $0$ for all other types of primitive groups?

Comment: @DerekHolt I was not referring to asymptotic results. I'm rather interessted in results for fixed $n$.

Comment: But then the answer will be highly dependent on $n$ and it will be extremely small for even moderately sized $n$. Could you try and ask a more precise question?